# Automate the selection of isolinux boot menu options

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, iso-image

I am trying to **fully automate** the testing of an **ISO installer**.

The ISO is bootable via ISOLINUX and can automatically install Oracle Linux 6 via Kickstart.

I have several `label` options in my `isolinux.cfg` file, each appending a different Kickstart file as follows:

```
foo
  kernel vmlinuz
  append ks=cdrom://isolinux/oel6-foo-ks.cfg 
bar
  kernel vmlinuz
  append ks=cdrom://isolinux/oel6-bar-ks.cfg
```

These labels help present the user with a boot menu, asking them what type of system to install (a *foo* or a *bar*).

Through VirtualBox command line, I can see how to create a VM with the ISO attached and power it on.

My problem is **how to interact with the boot menu** presented by the ISO?

In general, is there a way to automate the interaction with boot menus from the hypervisor command line?

If there is no *proper way* to interact with boot menus, could we perhaps bypass the boot menu and provide `append ks` options by hand via something like [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-unattended):

> `VBoxManage unattended install --extra-install-kernel-parameters=params`.

If possible, I would prefer to avoid changing the ISO (E.G. timeout-default to one menu option, or remove the menu entirely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--auxiliary-base-path` option

```
VBoxManage unattended install {name} --user={config['mcs']['user']} --password={config['mcs']['pwd']} \
    --auxiliary-base-path {aux}/ \
    --install-additions --iso={download} --country=SG  --post-install-template={cfg} --script-template={cfg}
```

You can then patch the isocfg files before starting the VM.  I use this to use Ubuntu 20.04 [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) instead of Debian installer to patch `isolinux-txt.cfg`

Comment: Thanks, this helped solve it for me: `--script-template="$KSFILE"` where `KSFILE` is the desired kickstart file, which has been extracted from the ISO on the host prior to booting the guest VM.